# How to insert existing XWPFParagraph into specific location in between other XWPFParagraphs of org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument?

Tags: java, apache-poi

Initially I have one DOCX template document. So I get 
org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument out of it and let's say it has 5 XWPFParagraphs like:

```
<w:document>
  <w:body>
    <w:p> ... </w:p>
    <w:p> ... </w:p>
    <w:p> ... </w:p>
    <w:p> ... </w:p>
    <w:p> ... </w:p>
  </w:body>
</w:document>
```

Then I grab one XWPFParagraph from another DOCX file and I need to insert it in between 2nd and 3rd XWPFParagraphs of initial document. Like this:

```
<w:document>
  <w:body>
    <w:p> ... </w:p>
    <w:p> ... </w:p>
    <w:p> inserted Paragraph  </w:p>
    <w:p> ... </w:p>
    <w:p> ... </w:p>
    <w:p> ... </w:p>
  </w:body>
</w:document>
```

How can I do it?

I can say what I tried:
- I tried to use [insertNewParagraph()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html#insertNewParagraph(org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor)) method, but it seams like it is creating new Paragraph, but I need to insert existing Paragraph that I grab from the other document.

```
private void insertParagraphAfter(XWPFParagraph p1, XWPFParagraph p2) {
    XWPFDocument doc = p1.getDocument();
    XmlCursor cursor = p1.getCTP().newCursor();
    XWPFParagraph newP = doc.insertNewParagraph(cursor);
    newP = p2;
}
```

But it does not seams to be working.

Comment: Generally you can only add "unattached" items, or have brand new ones created, not sure that an attempt to add a paragraph from a completely different document is going to go very well as there'd be all sorts of references that would break...

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution,

1. I can insert it not after but before current paragraph;
2. Need to copy all runs explicitly

[image]